# Do we need the tag [personalize]?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There is currently [one question](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/875/how-to-personalize-a-vocabulary-flashcard-deck-without-spending-too-much-time-on) with the tag [personalize](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/personalize), which was probably specifically created for this question.

I have two objections to it:

- Tags our typically nouns, not verbs, so `personalization` or `customization` would be more appropriate.
- I currently don't see much use for it.

So can we re-tag that question by removing the `personalize` tag from it, and then "burninate" the tag?

---

**Update**: the tag no longer exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is copied from my other meta answer on [this question](https://languagelearning.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/465/remove-speak-tag-or-make-it-a-synonym-of-speaking) because the answer is the same.)

Tags with no questions will automatically be removed by a script that runs every 24 hours. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it) for more information. "There is a script that runs daily to hide (soft-delete) tags that don't have any associated questions. All you need to do is remove the tag from your question, and the script will pick it up automatically."