# Remove 'speak' tag or make it a synonym of 'speaking'

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

A few minutes ago, I noticed that there is a [speak](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speak) tag, which has no questions. I don't know who created it.

Do we want to keep it? If yes, should it be made a synonym of the [speaking](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking), which currently has several questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Hatchet mentioned, tags with no questions will automatically be removed by a script that runs every 24 hours. See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71123/i-accidentally-created-a-tag-how-do-i-delete-it) for more information. "There is a script that runs daily to hide (soft-delete) tags that don't have any associated questions. All you need to do is remove the tag from your question, and the script will pick it up automatically."

If you really feel it's necessary, you can go ahead and add [speak](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speak) as a synonym of [speaking](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking), assuming of course that [you have an answer score of 5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) in [speaking](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking). It won't make a huge difference because [speak](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speak) will be gone soon anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Tags with no questions will be automatically deleted by the system.